# Meaning of 'She has some mouth on her'?

Tags: idioms

What’s the meaning of “she has some mouth on her”?
[image]

The idiom comes from an episode (S03E03) of *Seinfeld:*

> -He loves that pen.
>   -Come on.
>   He talks about it all the time.
>   He goes on and on about how it writes upside down, how astronauts use it.
>   He never should have offered it.
>   -He didn't think you'd accept.
>   -Well, he was wrong.
>   I know his wife.
>   **She has some mouth on her.** 
>   She'll tell everyone in the condo now that you made him give you the pen.
>   They're talking about it right now.

[Read more](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=seinfeld&episode=s03e03)

Comment: I can't find a definition, although there are quite a few examples on the Internet.  In general it means that the person of whom this is said uses language appropriate to a men's locker room or Army basic training.  If @cobaltduck thinks there's another interpretation, it would be interesting to hear it.  This particular quotation seems to be from an episode of Seinfeld, and I doubt a full text would provide defining context.

Comment: Oh wait.  Alternative interpretation would be that she has a beautiful or otherwise remarkable mouth.  In that case the use of this expression would be a mistake.

Comment: @Xanne--You were right the first time; don't second guess yourself.  When you say someone "has some mouth on her," you mean she uses coarse language and swears a lot.  She speaks inappropriately.  And you pronounce it with primary stress on both "some" and "mouth."

Comment: @xanne yea it’s an episode of seinfeld thanks for your answer

Comment: The original term was 'mouthy' meaning prone to talk back. That became 'some mouth' later, I believe.

Comment: It's important to note that the phrase _**some** mouth on her_ has to have the _some_ stressed. That means her mouth is notable, and in this context _mouth_ means the way she talks, which is judged as being outside some social convention by the speaker (who was probably a man).

Comment: @StevenLittman I think in this context it means that she talks *a lot,* which is still judged inappropriately, but it's more about being a gossip than about swearing.

Comment: @JohnLawler In the UK we would use the sentence with pretty much the same meaning but many of us would keep both 'some' and 'mouth' fairly evenly stressed but with a slight stress on 'some'.

Comment: To the extent that "She has some mouth on her" she will speak her mind, regardless… "Regardless…" here meaning without consideration of customs, feelings trampled, offence given, politeness or propriety, social mores or anything but what she thinks.

Answer (score 1):

**has a [some] mouth** in this context seems to imply:

> **big mouth**  a talkative person, especially one who lacks discretion. [dict.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bigmouth)

and:

> **shoot your mouth off** informal also shoot off at the mouth : to talk foolishly, carelessly, or too much about something
>
> ```
> She tends to shoot her mouth off.
> Try not to shoot your mouth off about this to anyone.
> ```
>
> [learnersdict.com](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/shoot)

lastly a **gossip**:

> : to talk about the personal lives of other people
>
> ```
> They spent the afternoon gossiping on the phone.
> They often gossip with each other about their neighbors.
> ```
>
> — gossiper noun, plural gossipers [count]
>
> ```
> a malicious gossiper.  [learnersdict.com][3]
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Im sure it means that the women/man is either rude or sassy. Since im only 12 Im unsure